# LinkedIn in-app browser forcing video to fullscreen on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, html5-video, linkedin-api

We are using LinkedIn to share a link to an HTML5 interactive video. When the link is shared, by default it opens in LinkedIn's browser inside the app. The problem is that when the user starts playing the video, the browser automatically switches to fullscreen, hiding our custom controls. iOS allows inline video playback nowadays with *playsinline* attribute on the video element, but LinkedIn browser doesn't support the attribute. On iPad the video does play inline though and does not switch to fullscreen. We have tested this bug on iOS versions 10 and 11. On native Safari browser or Google Chrome there's no problem, the video plays inline as intended. The video plays inline in other apps, for example Facebook Messenger's in-app browser. The only problem we have had is with the LinkedIn browser.

Is there any way to play a video inline on iPhone when using the in-app browser without going fullscreen? Or, is there any url scheme that could be used to launch Safari from the in-app browser? Currently the user experience is quite bad when the users have to manually exit fullscreen, which also pauses the video.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this ? The videos are played inline on iPad but not on iPhone which mimic the default behaviour of WkWebView.

Comment: Very interested if you found a solution to this. Struggling with it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the  target=”_blank” attribute. It will open the link provided in a new page, meaning it can open the video in a new page in the web browser.